# Python: Return string if substring in string

Tags: python, string, list, substring

I have two lists one has a bunch of paths ex: "C:\vol001\ABC123.xls" and the other has a bunch of names ex: "ABC123". I'm looking to find the paths if the name is in the path. So for the above example, the program would spit out "C:\vol001\ABC123.xls".

So far I've been trying to use the in operator, but I'm not sure how to return the path.

```
for name in list1:
    if name in list2:
        return path in list2
```

Comment: Would "C:\ABC123\test.xml" also match the name "ABC123"?

Comment: Ya, that would be fine. The paths are standard so the script can be flexible. For example the format will always be C:\vol001\NAME.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your initial solution is not correct. Actually, you are asking "is there 'name' **equal** one of the item in the list". But if you would like to test for **containment**, i.e. "whether 'name' is **part of** any item of the list" you should use something like code below:

```
for name in l2:
    return [x for x in l1 if name in x]
```

It is returns list of matched pathes. Actually it is just 2 *for* cycles rewritten in more pythonic way (as I remember it is called 'list comprehension', people who more familiar with terminology fixes me if I am wrong).

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
for path in list1:
    for name in list2:
        if name in path:
            return path
else:
    return None # not found
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
new_paths = []                          # create list for the paths to be kept
for path in paths:                      # cycle through paths
    for name in names:                  # cycle through names
        if name in path:                # check if path contains the name
            new_paths.append(path)      # path is good, so add to the list
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking into consideration your comment, that it doesn't matter where in the path the name appears (i.e. both "C:\ABC123\test.png" and "C:\vol01\ABC123.xml" match the query "ABC123"), we do not take into consideration the structure of the file system paths, but can work on pure string matching.

Be `paths` the list of all paths, be `names` the list of all names, and be `name` the name you are looking for then

```
(path for path in paths if name in path)
```

is the generator yielding all paths matching name.

```
dict ( ( (name, [path for path in paths if name in path] ) for name in names) )
```

creates a dictionary whose keys are the names and whose values are all paths that contain the corresponding name. You can use it someway like that:

```
paths = [....]
names = [....]
d = dict ( ( (name, [path for path in paths if name in path] ) for name in names) )
print ('The name "ABC" is contained in: {}'.format (d ['ABC'] ) )
print ('The name "XYZ" is contained in: {}'.format (d ['XYZ'] ) )
print ('The name "pron" is contained in: {} different paths'.format (len (d ['pron'] ) if 'pron' in d else 0) )
```

Answer (score -1):

`return os.path.dirname(name)`

Keep in mind that you have to run `import os.path` if you haven't already. See the [documentation for the os.path module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html).

Comment: OP asked about finding substring in list of strings. How os.path helps him?